# ¿Cómo puedo conectarme a un PLC vía Modbus usando Python?

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo conectarme a un `PLC` vía `Modbus` usando `Python`? Quiero ver los registros del `PLC` y para ello tengo que conectar mi PC al `PLC` y ver sus registros. Soy nuevo en `Python` y no sé muy bien como hacerlo. He leído algo acerca de un módulo `ModbusTcpClient` pero no sé como utilizarlo. Me gustaría hacer un programa para conectarme y monitorizar los registros del `PLC` en tiempo real.

Comment: `ModbusTcpClient` es una clase incluida en la biblioteca `pymodbus`. Te he puesto enlace a ella, proceso de instalación y el ejemplo que viene (aunque hay muchos más ejemplos en la documentación oficial).

Comment: ¿Cómo llevas el tema? Me he acordado de ti hoy porque hemos tenido una incidencia con el concentrador PLC de los equipos de climatización :)

Answer (score 3):

Hay disponibles dos bibliotecas python llamadas [pymodbus](https://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus) y [pymodbus3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymodbus3/1.0.0) que podrían ayudarte a conseguir lo que deseas.

NOTA: Viendo que `pymodbus3` lleva años sin actualizarse te recomiendo usar `pymodbus`. La forma de instalarlo es:

**Usando `pip`**

```
pip install  -U pymodbus
```

**Descargando el código:**

```
git clone git://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus.git
cd pymodbus
python setup.py install
```

---

Te vienen los siguientes códigos de ejemplo:

**Ejemplo usando `pymodbus` (recomendado)**

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('127.0.0.1')
client.write_coil(1, True)
result = client.read_coils(1,1)
print result.bits[0]
client.close()
```

**Ejemplo usando `pymodbus3` (obsoleto)**

```
from pymodbus3.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('127.0.0.1')
client.write_coil(1, True)
result = client.read_coils(1,1)
print result.bits[0]
client.close()
```

Comment: Me parece que este código es el que necesito pero no lo entiendo muy bien.

from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('127.0.0.1')
client.write_coil(1, True)
result = client.read_coils(1,1)
print result.bits[0]
client.close()

La idea es conectarme al PLC y consultar sus registros.

Comment: ¿Pero tienes su dirección IP? En el ejemplo se usa `localhost` (`127.0.0.1` hace referencia al mismo equipo en el que se ejecuta el código) pero es obvio que querrás acceder a un dispositivo que está en otra dirección IP. ¿Qué modelo de PLC tienes? ¿Lo conectas por puerto serie, USB o ethernet? Los que usamos en mi empresa usan un cable propietario (no sé cómo se llama) y accedemos a ellos a través de un concentrador que tiene conectividad ethernet, así que no te puedo ayudar más sin más información acerca del PLC al que quieres acceder.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia, sí tengo la IP real y el puerto. Tengo que acceder al PLC para ver sus registros. Sabes como puedo consultar esos registros? o sacarlos por pantalla?

Comment: Puedes usar [el `scrapper` del ejemplo](http://pythonhosted.org/pymodbus/examples/modbus-scraper.html) de la biblioteca `pymodbus`. Puedes elegir qué rango de registros consultar con el modificador `-r` o `--range`, por defecto `0:500`.

Comment: como sería con el scrapper, nunca lo he utilizado. Tengo la IP y el puerto del PLC, solamente necesito un fichero que lea los registros vía Modbus.